# How to catch OptimisticLockException in JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa, ejb, optimistic-locking

I've read out a couple of questions here regarding the `OptimisticLockException` with JPA, used in an stateless session bean. It is thrown, but not where I expect it obviously.

Here is the code where I expect to get the exception:

```
            try
            {
                productFacade.edit(product);
            }
            catch(Exception {
                return "lock";
            }
```

The `productFacade` is generated with NetBeans and it is an EJB with a local interface, an it implements an `AbstractFacade` abstract class. As far as I read, this has something to do with transactions in JPA. Because the exception is thrown after the method this code snippet is in is left, not after `edit()` is called. Where should I than handle the exception?

Also, I will be needing the transaction mechanism for later, because I will need to update multiple products (or none if some is locked). I've found some code examples, but this leaves me wondering how should I work with transactions?

Comment: Can you add more code, there isn't any relevant code displayed, how the transactions are managed, does the next method executes within same transaction etc.

Comment: I'm using JTA and Container based transactions. I've tried switching to bean controlled transactions and manage my own transactions, but that didn't really help.
How can I check does the next method execute within the same transaction?

Comment: As previously mentioned, update the post with relevant code, will help everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lock error will not be thrown until the transaction commits.  So you would need to handle it outside of your SessionBean or use a container managed transaction.

Or, you could just call flush() on your JPA EntityManager, then the error will be thrown.

Comment: I am using container managed transactions. Where could I catch the exception out of the session bean, on the client?
With container managed transactions, when do transactions actually start and end? If I do multiple merges in one method, will they be considered a transaction after the method ends?

Answer (score 0):

use save and flash and catch with `Exception`

```
try {
  log.info("save data versions: " + employee.getVersion());
  someRepository.saveAndFlush(employee);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  log.info("catch Exception");
  throw new OptimisticLockException("retry data Exception");
}
```

if want to use retry can add anotation `@Retryable` with some flagging